# Show time since post was made

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a status page project for my home lab. I want to be able to do a time since where the status updates have a time and then the user's system takes the current server time and figure out how long since I sent that out.

So far I just have the route for creating a new status and then a show route.

**NEW STATUS ROUTE**

```
router.post("/status/new", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    var type = req.body.type;
    var message = req.body.message;
    var date = new Date();
    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    };
    var newStatus = {type:type, message:message, author:author, date:date};
    Status.create(newStatus, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            throw(err);
        } else {
            //redirect back to new status page
            res.redirect("/admin/status/new");
        }
    });

});
```

**SHOW STATUS ROUTE**

```
//root route
router.get("/", function(req, res){
    Status.find({}, function(err, allStatuses){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   } else {

       var second = 1000,
       minute = 1000 * 60,
       hour = minute * 60,
       day = hour * 24,
       year = day * 365,
       time = Date.now();

       var diff = time - allStatuses[0].date,
       seconds = Math.round(diff / second),
       minutes = Math.round(diff / minute),
       hours = Math.round(diff / hour),
       days = Math.round(diff / day),
       years = Math.round(diff / year);

       console.log("Difference: " + diff);
       if (diff < 1 * minute) {
           console.log(seconds + " seconds ago");
       }
       if (diff > 1 * minute && diff < 1 * hour) {
           console.log(minutes + " minutes ago");
       }
       if (diff > 1 * hour && diff < 1 * day) {
           console.log(hours + " hours ago");
       }
       if (diff > 1 * day && diff < 1 * year) {
           console.log(days + " days ago");
       }
       if (diff > 1 * year) {
           console.log(years + " years ago");
       }


      res.render("index", {statuses:allStatuses});
   }
 });
});
```

**CODE I AM USING FOR FIRST LINE OF EJS ARRAY**

```
<% statuses.forEach(function(status){ %>
```

I have used moment.js before but never for something like this. I am not even to sure how to go about solving this problem. Any guidance or suggestions are welcome. I can't seem to get any compares working. I figure that I need to take the current time, minus the time of creation then calculate the reminder and figure out seconds,minutes, hours, days, weeks, months and years.

I can seem to figure out how to do `Date.now()` then save that to the database and then do a `Date.now()` on page load and come up with the miliseconds difference but I am unsure how to take the difference I find and then pass it through to my template. I know how to pass arrays through but I can't seem to come up with a way to take the array from the query, then take and find the time differences from each one, save it in an array, then be able to loop through it inside my template where I am already looping through the query returned array.

All tries I have gone through involve looping through the entire differences array for each  status/post.

Answer (score 0):

You could do yourself or you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

In the first case, use:

```
var diff = time.getTime() - allStatuses[0].date.getTime();
```

This way you have the time difference in miliseconds. Then you can format as you wish.

But with moment it gets easier, using [fromNow()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) method:

```
var diff = moment(allStatuses[0].date).fromNow();
```

In this case, diff is already the string you need to print to user.

Of course, you probably want to do that in a loop instead of just allStatus[0].

Comment: I knew moment could do it but couldn't find it so figured I was crazy. How can I take that moment function and then loop through all it all I tried this `var diff = new Array();
            for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
                diff[i] = moment(allStatuses[i].date).fromNow();
            } `

And I get a `Cannot read property 'date' of undefined` but I know there is 3 items in the array. I can console.log the query array and get the right output for it

Comment: Does that work: `var diff = []; for (var i = 0; i < allStatuses.length; i++) { diff.push(moment(allStatuses[i].date).fromNow(); }` ?